# How to implement firebase with mobile number login in angular 8?

Tags: angular8

How can i integrate firebase with mobile login in angular 8 using otp method. Please somebody help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fireship is a great channel on YouTube with Angular and Firebase tutorials (and many more)

I think this one is what you are looking for:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIq_VU1Njw0

It's in Angular 4, but I don't that is going to be a problem.